# Adding OCaml support to bashrc

Tags: bash, terminal, ocaml

This has been flagged as a duplicate but the solution described in the possible duplicate is what I have tried and it did not work for me.

I installed OCaml and the installer said to add `/Users/me/ocamlbrew/ocaml-4.02.3/etc/ocamlbrew.bashrc` to my .bashrc file I did so and it doesnt seem to help.

I have to run `/Users/me/ocamlbrew/ocaml-4.02.3/etc/ocamlbrew.bashrc` on every new terminal window before I can use `Ocaml` as a command. What can I do to avoid this?

This is what I tried:

```
alias ocaml = source /Users/me/ocamlbrew/ocaml-4.02.3/etc/ocamlbrew.bashrc
```

I also tried

```
source /Users/me/ocamlbrew/ocaml-4.02.3/etc/ocamlbrew.bashrc
```

I've tried editing my ~/.bashrc file and my ~/.bash_profile

Comment: @Kenney I made an edit.

Comment: Ok that should work - but you still have to type `ocaml`.

Comment: @Kenney Tried that and it didn't work. Can you undo that so that people will answer my question.

Comment: @chepner I did and it didnt work. I have that in my post and in a comment.

Comment: What operating system are you using? If Mac OS X, most terminal emulators run a login shell instead of a regular interactive shell, so you would need to add that line to `.bash_profile` (creating it, if necessary) instead.

Comment: @chepner Im on a mac. I added that line to my ~/.bash_profile and it didnt work.

Comment: You are not allowed to have whitespace on either side of the equals sign. This is a common FAQ; voting to close as trivial typo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up adding source `/Users/me/ocamlbrew/ocaml-4.02.3/etc/ocamlbrew.bashrc` to (the installer lied about where to do this) my `~/.bash_profile` and then calling source `~/.bash_profile`from the terminal.

Comment: The installer didn't lie; it simply assumed a more traditional Unix-style setup, where terminal emulators are ultimately spawned from a shell session. Mac OS X terminal emulators are different, since there is no initial shell session for them to inherit their environment from, so every window starts a login shell.

Comment: @chepner I get why it said the wrong thing but it still said the wrong thing without any qualifications.